# How to do Virtual Device Testing other than Android Emulator?

Tags: android, android-studio, runtime, compatibility

I need to test my app in different varieties of devices.But buying physical devices are costly and not practical.What are the possible ways of testing my app in varieties of Virtual Devices?

Comment: I cannot buy every device so i want to check it virtually

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple options you can use instead of physical device as following

1. [GenyMotion](https://www.genymotion.com/)
2. [Firebase TestLab](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/fir-demo-project/testlab/histories)
3. [Amazon Device Farm](https://aws.amazon.com/device-farm/)

Comment: @faisal-liaquat Please accept the answer,If it covers your problem.

Comment: i accepted it sso long and its giving this

Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.